# Extract time from a date/time variable PHP

Tags: php

I have an external variable coming in a file in the following format:

```
<?php  $var = JHtml::_('date', $item->event_date, this->config->event_date_format, null) ;  ?>
```

which outputs something like this:

```
09-05-2015 6:00 am
```

How can I remove the date part and keep only the hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for this

```
 $date = '09-05-2015 6:00 am';
 echo $time=date("g", strtotime($date));
```

**OUTPUT**

> 6

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. strtotime() can transform this date into a php-readable date. You can choose which items you want to show (hour, seconds, day, etc). http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#format

```
date('H:s', strtotime($var));
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to use substr:

```
substr($var, -7);
```